# ListView inside Fragment inside Activity is not match_parent-ing?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm using a `Fragment` inside an `Activity` and the `ListView` is located inside my `Fragment`.

I have set everything to `match_parent` but it works in the way that not I'm expecting.

Please refer to this image for better understanding https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzkpg.jpg
(Not enough reputation =.= cannot post image)

To save our time, I have omitted most of the unnecessary code, if you need me to provide more codes, please tell me.

Thanks.

---

activity_book_information.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

...

<!-- Fragments -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_line2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_book_review.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reviewAddReview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bookInfo_addReview"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_review"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_review_single.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_row_curve_rectangle_box">

<!-- Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/book_reviewName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Name"/>

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

## Java

BookInformationActivity.java

```
public class BookInformationActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_information);

        f_manager = getFragmentManager();
        f_transaction = f_manager.beginTransaction();
        f_transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView, new BookReviewFragment(), "f_bookReview");
        f_transaction.commit();
    }
    ...
}
```

BookReviewFragment.java

```
public class BookReviewFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_review, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        list = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.list_review);
        new GetReviewTask().execute();
    }

    public class GetReviewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ...
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ...
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if(aBoolean != null) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new GetReviewAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_review_single, reviewList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter); // TODO : Fix Layout issue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your activity_book_information.xml. Need to see where your f_bookReview is.

Comment: @tachonflux the first xml is 'activity_book_information.xml', f_bookReview is just a 'Tag'.

Comment: oh whoops, why are you using a ScrollView as a fragment?

Comment: @tachonflux, It is a bad approach. I wasn't aware that will cause the problem. I have changed to `LinearLayout` and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you adding your fragment inside a `ScrollView`?? Change this scroll view to a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and it would work fine.

`ScrollView` and `ListView` can't work together properly. They both have their own scrolling property.

**Workaround (but not a good way)**

But if anyway you want to do it then do this in your fragment, **I wouldn't suggest it though.**

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren()
{
    float offset = 1;

    BaseAdapter listAdapter = (BaseAdapter) gridView.getAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    for(int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, gridView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight() + (offset * scale);
    }
    params.height = (int) (totalHeight + (offset * scale * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1)));
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: I changed the `ScrollView` to `LinearLayout` and it works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have multiple views inside my Scrollview including a listview , so I have to use a Scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Try to set on linearLayout weightSum:"7" attribute into your xml and then layout_weight="1" for button and layout_weight="6" for your listView (assuming that the list view has the 6/7 of the space).

Comment: This isn't the problem. It won't help.